# adding multiple localized files

Tags: xcode

I've got to add multiple localized files to my project.
If I understand correctly I should

1. add the files in one language to my project (in english for example)
2. select each files and add a new language, this will copy my files in
   the en.lprj and fr.lproj
3. overwrite my french files in fr.lproj

This is fastidious, is there a better way?

Comment: did it as I said, fastidious but done! I remain interested by another method